# Getting id of Asp.Net MVC Auto Complete TextBox

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a Textbox where I am getting Json Data to show data in textbox

```
@Html.TextBox("tbxSearch", null, new { data_url = Url.Action("GetSearchData"), data_maxValues = 10, data_valueHiddenId = "#value" })
```

On typing in textbox I am getting Json Data as

```
[{"label":"ABC","value":186},{"label":"DEF","value":1744}]
```

My Question is I have a button and on click on button I need value of selected item in textbox.

I am trying this way

```
 $("#btnSearchPerson").click(function () {
        alert($('#tbxSearch').data('valueHiddenId'));
});
```

It shows undefined. Please guide me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery `data-*` attributes are lowercased when parsed.

```
$("#btnSearchPerson").click(function () {
  alert($('#tbxSearch').data('valuehiddenid'));
});
```

If you want to have camel cased `data-*` attributes separate words with a `-`

```
<div data-value-Hidden-Id="some value">
</div>
```

And the jQuery

```
$("#btnSearchPerson").click(function () {
  alert($('#tbxSearch').data('valueHiddenId'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use $('#tbxSearch').attr('data-valueHiddenId') instead